# Optimize autohotkey code / send keyboard code

Tags: autohotkey

I'm impressed with what AutoHotkey can do. How can I optimize that code? What do I need to know?

```
SetTitleMatchMode RegEx ;

::/act1::
Send {LControl down}
Send {LShift down}
Send {m}
Send {LControl up}
Send {LShift up}
Send {Left 3}
Send {LShift down}
Send {Home}
Send {LShift up}
Send {LControl down}
Send {c}
Send {LControl up}
WinActivate WidnowA
Send {LControl down}
Send {Home}
Send {LControl up}
Send {Down 1}
Send {Right 12}
Send {LControl down}+{v}
Send {LControl up}
Send {,}
Send {Space}
Send {LControl down}
Send {s}
Send {LControl up}
CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
x := 150
y := 1420
Click %x% %Y%
Send {Right 3}
return
```

I think that no need to describe the sections, but.. can I write it another (easiest) way?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Along with the possible typo David found, you can condense a lot of your send commands into one line. Also, does it need to be left control and shift or will either do? I've written it below without specifying.

```
SetTitleMatchMode , RegEx
CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
::/act1::
Send , ^+m{left 3}+{home}^c
WinActivate , WindowA
Send , ^{home}{down}{right 12}^v{,}{space}^s
Click , 150 , 1420
Send , {right 3}
Return
```

As far as writing it an easier way, it will help to know what you're trying to accomplish. It's likely that what you're trying to do can be done more reliablely by manipulating controls directly instead of sending keystrokes.

Comment: Keep in mind that merely condensing your lines down isn't optimisation. It doesn't improve performance and negatively impacts readability just to save a bit on the line count. Additionally, using SendInput is recommended over Send. Be careful about not checking for the active window or otherwise accounting for performance delays. With no sleep commands or other checks, the hotkey combos may be performed faster than the system can keep up at.

Comment: The last question that was asked, "but.. can I write it another (easiest) way?" is what my answer is about. I'm not sure how that earned a downvote, especially since it worked for OP, but whatever.

Comment: Fair enough on "easiest" as the author may not understand the difference. Downvote was a misclick; apologies. Can't modify it without the post being edited. Score one for bad UX design by Stack Exchange.

Comment: Understood, no problem. Also, just a note about optimization: I ran `Send , {space 2000}` vs 2,000 lines of standalone lines of `Send , {space}`. The results were 328ms vs 641ms, or a little over half the time. As for readability, I would argue strongly that my version of the code is much more readable than the original, mainly due to the symbols the represent the modifier keys; otherwise, that would be personal preference at best and bad practice at worst.

Answer (score -1):

I don't see a lot of room to optimize here as there isn't much repetition going on. If you had the same series of keystrokes being used, you could reduce repetition with a function. However, it does appear that you have a typo at "WinActivate WidnowA"

One possible improvement is changing your use of "Send" to "[SendInput](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#Send_variants)" which is "generally faster and more reliable".